# Why do I get a Windows Installer popup whenever I build a project in Visual Studio 2010 or 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I attempt to build a project in Visual Studio 2010 or 2013, I get a Windows Installer popup that says "Please wait while Windows configures Visual Studio".

How can I make this popup go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root Cause:**
Windows thinks that the installation is broken because of a missing folder.

**Proper Solution:**
Uninstall and reinstall the affected versions of Visual Studio.

**Workaround**
Create the following empty folder

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC
```

The presence of this folder will stop the popup from appearing.